# Order of operations precedence / loops

Tags: c, loops, operator-precedence

In the C programming language:

1. [This](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) I do not understand. Is it saying that (for example) if += is after -= in a statement, the += is evaluated first? Or if * is before a -, the - is executed first? I need to understand precedence.
2. Can someone write me  two or three complicated loops which include: a few counter variables, 3 or 4 or 5 loops within eachother, arrays, printf's and strings and stuff? I need to learn to manually go through loops on paper really well if I want to ace my programming course, or the exam I have tomorrow..

This is nit homework, i.e., nothing to hand in, just preparing for my exam in C tomorrow.

Comment: If these are two separate questions, you should ask them as two separate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The precedence chart has a vertical component (precedence) and a horizontal component (associativity).

Basically, operations higher in the list are done first, so `a + b * c` is evaluated as `a + (b * c)`. Note that this doesn't mean that `b * c` is calculated before `a`, just that the `*` operation is done before the `+`. An implementation is free to calculate `a` first, *then* multiply `b` and `c` and add that to the already calculated `a`.

For simple expressions, this makes no difference but it can bite you if one of the terms of your expression has a side-effect beyond supplying a simple value. By that, I means things like `i++` which has the side-effect of incrementing `i`, or a call to a function which modifies global variables, or writes information to a database.

Where two operators have the *same* precedence, associativity takes over. This dictates how operations with the *same* precedence group together.

So `+` and `-` (which have associativity of left to right) means that `a + b - c` evaluates as `(a + b) - c`.

On the other hand, `+=` and `-=` have right-to-left associativity so that `a += b -= c` evaluates as `a += (b -= c)`.

---

In terms of loops, you can start with the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define WIDTH 5
#define HEIGHT 7
int main (void) {
    int num[WIDTH*HEIGHT];
    int counter = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
            num[i*WIDTH+j] = --counter;
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            printf ("%3d ", num[i*WIDTH+j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would suggest you have a quick try in understanding it, *then* type it in to compile and run.

Comment: More succinct than what I was going to write.

Comment: Operations higher in the list are *not* "done first".  This misunderstanding is the root of many bugs.

Comment: @caf, I'd be interested in what sort of bug you've found by assuming that higher precedence operators are done first. I can see it would be a problem with the associativity bit (`a + b + c` may evaluate `b` first) but, short of not actually _using_ a subexpression, those with a higher precedence would have to be calculated first.

Comment: Given the expression `a * b + c`, `a * b` must be evaluated before you can add it to the result of `c`; however, that doesn't mean that the expression `c` can't be evaluated before `a * b`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: One sub-class involves function calls - eg. assuming that in `f() * j + g()`, `f()` must be evaluated before `g()`.  But the same misunderstanding (that precedence implies something about order of evaluation) is at the root of all those "undefined behaviour" questions involving multiple use of the `++` / `--` operators on the same objects.  I think a good understanding of when C specifies an order, and when it doesn't, is quite important.

Comment: Point taken, I've tried to clarify that it's the order of the _operations_ rather than the _evaluation of the terms_ which the precedence controls. I'm happy for any advice on how that could be made clearer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

1) "Operators on the same line in the chart have the same precedence," so `a + b - c` evaluates as `(a + b) - c`. Read that page from top to bottom to get the order of operations. So for `a + b + (c * ++d)` the order would be add 1 to d, multiply that by c, and then add that whole quantity to the quantity `a + b`.

2) For loops just read through like a normal book, top to bottom. For example: (pseudocode corrected to proper C -zw)

```
int i, j, k;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        for (k = 10; k > 0; k = k/2)
            printf("%d %d %d\n", k, j, i);
```

You start with i as 0, and j as 0, i and j stay 0 while k is 10, 5, 2, 1, then you go back up and j is 1 while i remains 0 and k is 10, 5, 2, 1. Repeat until j is 10, then go back up and make i 1. Repeat this whole thing until i is 100. An internal loop is run to completion for every value of the proceeding loop.

Comment: I marked you as best answer or whatever because you helped me understand the table and you gave me a decent loop to go through + explained it. Also, I'm going to need something harder than that.

Comment: paxdiablo is correct.  In the circumstances I'm just gonna go ahead and fix that for you.

Comment: quick tests prove I was indeed misled. When I first learned c++ I was told that order of operations was not the same as in mathematics and as such have always used parenthesis to guarantee appropriate order of operations. Thanks for the corrections

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence and associativity does not specify the *order* in which C evaluates expressions.  It specifies how subexpressions are grouped together.

`+=` and `-=` have equal precedence, and associate right-to-left.  This means that in this expression:

```
a += b -= c
```

C groups it as:

```
a += (b -= c)
```

So the value that is subtracted from `b` is `c`, and the value that is added to `a` is the result of the expression `b -= c` (which is the new value of `b`).  The order in which this actually occurs is not specified.

---

Try this nested loop out - what is it doing?

```
int check(const char *entries[], size_t num_entries)
{
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < num_entries; i++)
    {
        size_t ilen = strlen(entries[i]);

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            size_t jlen = strlen(entries[j]);

            if (jlen >= ilen && !memcmp(entries[i], entries[j], ilen))
            {
                count++;
                printf("%s@%d shadows %s@%d.\n", entries[j], j, entries[i], i);
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```